# Angular 2 ngControl without ngFormModel

Tags: angular

So I'm a bit confused about ngControl & ngFormModel. In my mind, it makes since that if I declare a ControlGroup programmatically, I shouldn't need to have an ngFormModel (html form rather) explicitly tying all my controls together in html.

Given the code below, this will not work unless I wrap my inputs in the same form object in HTML and orchestrated off of its name.

```
@Component({
    selector: "login-form",
    template: `
        <div>
            <input type="text" ngControl="usernameControl" [ngClass]="{'has-error': !usernameControl.valid}" />
            <input type="password" ngControl="passwordControl" [ngClass]="{'has-error': !passwordControl.valid}"/>
        </div>
    `
export class VenueCard{
    usernameControl: Control;
    passwordControl: Control;
    loginFormGroup: ControlGroup;

    constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder){
        this.usernameControl = new Control("", Validators.minLength(2));
        this.passwordControl = new Control("", Validators.minLength(6));

        this.loginFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
            username: this.usernameControl,
            password: this.passwordControl});
    }

    submitForm(){
        if (!this.loginFormGroup.valid){return;}
        // Use usernameControl.value & passwordControl.value now
    }
}
```

What I expect, is that I can bind an individual input element to a ngControl property and it will keep track of its own validity. The formGroup would just be a quick way for me to check all controls but is not needed. Am I just not setting this up correctly or am I fundamentally missing something with my mindset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngFormControl` as below and as in this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/HzBjCVLiXcCfv1ZBcG3D?p=preview):

```
@Component({
    selector: "login-form",
    directives:[NgFormControl],
    template: `
        <div>
            <input type="text" [ngFormControl]="usernameControl" [ngClass]="{'has-error': !usernameControl.valid}" />
            <input type="password" [ngFormControl]="passwordControl" [ngClass]="{'has-error': !passwordControl.valid}"/>
        </div>
    `
})
export class VenueCard{
    ...
}
```